# Transfer mysql database between servers

Tags: mysql, database, linux, centos

I have to move a large mysql (only MYISAM/MEMORY tables) database between two VPS servers with the same mysql version and I attempted to import using mysqldump but it takes far to long time and the ssh session timed out. So is it possible to simply transfer the database folder in the mysql datadir from one server to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can copy the myisam datafiles across granted that the architecture of the servers is the same.  If you copy the files over, you'll have to create users, permissions etc. on the new server.  However, I would still try to get your mysqldump script to work before you jump into that.

This is covered by a number of people [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another)

If you are saying that you have a problem simply due to losing your ssh session, then look into installation of screen on your server, and start a screen session.  It exists to handle those types of problems.

In terms of performance, did you utilize the [extended_insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert) and possibly [delayed insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_delayed-insert) options when you did your dump?